# If I arrive in the UK, and then head to mainland Europe, does my Schengen visa 90 day limit start when I arrived in the UK, or mainland Europe?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

As the UK is technically still a member of the EU, I just wanted to be sure of this before booking travel arrangements.

The idea is to arrive in the UK and stay there for 2-4 weeks, and then afterwards relocate to and stay in mainland Europe for another 80-90 days. Is this possible? Or would I be effectively limited to 70 days in the EU after staying for example 20 days in the UK?

Comment: The UK has never been part of the Schengen area.

Comment: Side note: please check whether you need a visa for the UK as well, as your Schengen visa will not cover entry to the UK.

Comment: The trick here is that there's nothing governing your time in the EU.  The Schengen area and the UK are separate immigration territories, and their time constraints for visitors are reckoned separately.

Comment: it starts when you arrive in the Schengen Area...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Isn't that implied by the question? If the UK was in Schengen, then this question wouldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The 90 day clock starts when you arrive in mainland Europe.

The UK isn't in the Schengen Area, so your time there has no effect on your Schengen time limit.

It's worth noting that the EU and Schengen Area, while related, are different things: several countries (UK, Ireland, Bulgaria, Romania, Cyprus, Croatia) are in the EU but not Schengen, while some (Switzerland, Norway, Iceland) are in Schengen but not the EU.

Comment: https://i2.wp.com/craphound.com/images/5509980924_8227fac906_b.jpg?w=970 is helpful to see the many different relations. (It does not show the Common Travel Area comprising the United Kingdom, Ireland, the Isle of Man, and the Channel Island which is just as well because there's not a soul alive who'd know what happens to the CTA after Brexit. If there's a Brexit.)

Comment: @chx This graphic appear to be out-of-date, since Liechtenstein is a member of the Schengen Area.

Comment: @chx Irish and British governments have already said the CTA will stay after brexit...

Comment: I said Irish government too not just British @MSalters. Irish and British citizens hold more rights in each others countries that EU citizens, the CTA goes back before EU treaties. Its nothing to do with being in the EU or not.

Comment: @BritishSam: On closer inspection, you're right. The CTA is probably necessary for the Good Friday Agreement.

Comment: @BritishSam they said many things.

Comment: @DanM. a deal has been signed, agreement is in place https://www.ft.com/content/2b3fccf4-7186-11e9-bf5c-6eeb837566c5

Comment: @BritishSam it's behind the paywall. And similar things had been said about EU and similar deals (and Brexit as a whole). So I remain skeptical until it actually happens.

Comment: "in mainland Europe" is imprecise.  It really should be "in the Schengen area."  Some counterexamples are Iceland, Azores, etc. (Schengen area, not mainland) and Bosnia, Croatia, etc. (mainland, not Schengen area).

Comment: @MSalters regardless of whether the CTA is necessary for the GFA, it preceded the GFA by about 75 years.  It also preceded the start of the late-twentieth-century troubles by about 45 years.  Similarly, the customs union preceded the GFA. The CTA existed in the absence of a customs union for decades; there were customs controls, but no immigration controls, for about 70 years. But the GFA actually says nothing about border controls of any kind.

Comment: @phoog That’s incorrect. The GFA commits the UK government to removing “security installations”. Customs posts on the border are security installations, of very much the kind envisaged in the GFA.

Comment: @MikeScott no, security installations are military-style security checkpoints.  Customs controls had been removed in 1993; there was no reason for customs controls to be under discussion at all.  Yes, my statement was overbroad, in that it overlooked the mention of "security installations," but I do not accept that the imposition of customs checks would violate the GFA.  The paragraph commits the UK to "progress towards the objective of as early a return as possible to normal security arrangements in Northern Ireland," and for 70 years, normal security arrangements included customs posts.

Answer (score 15):

Your stay in the U.K. does not count towards your Schengen stay limits. They are completely separate visa regimes.

Even if you stay for a whole 6 months in the U.K., it still is 0 days  in the Schengen area.

Your proposed plan is perfectly fine. Your 90 day Schengen limit will start when you enter the Schengen zone, not when you enter the U.K.